# 'ng generate service' command says 'Nothing to be done'

Tags: angular, angular-services

I want to create a service service file. But when I am giving
`ng generate service my-service` it returns 'Nothing to be done'.
There doesn't exist a file with the same name in my project folder.
Version I am using:
**Angular CLI: 16.2.0
Node: 18.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
Angular: 16.2.1**

Comment: have you made sure your terminal is running in the directory your project is in? you can check with `pwd` (print working directory). your terminal _might_ be somewhere there there is a "my-service" that already exists

Comment: Yes, I am running in the same directory